# Can you get the request method in a DRF ModelViewSet?

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am building a Django chat app that uses Django Rest Framework. I created a MessageViewSet that extends ModelViewSet to show all of the message objects:

```py
class MessageViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
```

This chat app also uses Channels and when a user sends a POST request, I would like to do something channels-realted, but I can't find a way to see what kind of request is made. Is there any way to access the request method in a ModelViewSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rest Framework **[`viewsets`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)** map the http methods: **`GET`**, **`PUT`**, **`POST`**, and **`DELETE`** to view methods named **`list`**, **`update`**, **`create`**, and **`destroy`** respectively; so in your case, you would need to override the **`create`** method:

```
class MessageViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        print('this is a post request', request)
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

we can't get 'GET' request because ModelViewSet is inherited from
mixins.CreateModelMixin,mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
mixins.DestroyModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet
these mixins so instead of 'GET' request we can override list method

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwe0K.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).